# Passing parameters between angular components not working

Tags: angular, events, components, observable, parameter-passing

I am writing an angular program. It has 2 components (property-value and purchase-expenses). Both are embedded in app.component.html. I want if a parameter changes in property-value, a change should reflect in purchase-expenses. The components are not in the parent-child relationship.

I have used Observable in the service class, but it seems the subscribed portion of the code in PurchaseExpensesComponent is not getting invoked as a result, the change is not reflecting in the purchase-expenses component UI.

I not sure why. Any help will be appreciated.

Code -

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lvhkuv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already providing the CashflowService in the root module:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CashFlowService {
```

... so you should remove or comment the line `providers:` in the `PurchaseExpensesComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-purchase-expenses',
  templateUrl: './purchase-expenses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./purchase-expenses.component.css'],
  //providers: [CashFlowService] <==== REMOVE OR COMMENT THIS LINE
})
```

... and in the `PropertyValueComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-property-value',
  templateUrl: './property-value.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./property-value.component.css'],
  //providers: [CashFlowService] <==== REMOVE OR COMMENT THIS LINE
})
```

So, your are providing a local instance of the service for each component and each component is calling the methods of its own instance. Instead you should have a singleton service shared by all components.

Check this stackblitz I made based on your code. The only changes are the ones mentioned above: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7uuarq

Comment: And by the way, congrats for providing a Stackblitz of your code. That makes a lot easier to try to help!

Comment: This resolved the issue. @kari Thanks a lot for helping. I am new to angular. I hope i am implementing it correctly.